# cy.visit() does not recognize a URL being passed in as an argument

Tags: cypress, cypress-mailosaur

This is my first time using Cypress (and first SO post) and I keep running into an error. First, here is my code:

```js
describe('Add new user to existing clinic team', () => {

    const serverId = 'e6ar8r9c';
      const testEmail = 'something@e6ar8r9c.mailosaur.net'
      let confirmationLink

      it('signs in as admin', () => {
    cy.visit('******')
    cy.get('#user_email').type('*******')
    cy.get('#user_password').type('******')
    cy.get('.button').click()
  
    // show teams roster
    cy.get('.hide-for-large > a > .fas').click()          
    cy.get('.vertical > :nth-child(1) > #programs-menu-btn > .fas').click()
    
    // click into the clinic team
    cy.get('table tbody > tr').contains('clinic team test apr 28#4').click()

    // click into the user roster for the clinic team
    cy.get('ul#program-team-tabs > li#team-icon-li').click()

    // enter user email to be added
    cy.get('#email').type(testEmail)
    cy.get('button.non-button').click()

    // get email
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: testEmail
    }).then(email => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Existing user invitation instructions');
      cy.log(email.subject)
      cy.log(email.html.links[0].href)
      confirmationLink = email.html.links[0].href
    })
  
    // follow email link
    cy.visit(confirmationLink)    
  })
})
```

When it logs the email link to the console, it logs the full URL of the link. However, it prints this error: "cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argument" as if confirmationLink doesn't contain a URL, which, according to the console log, it does. Why is it not recognizing the URL?

Comment: what is the value of `confirationLink` that is being passed to `cy.visit()` ?

Comment: "https://********.com/users/invitation/accept?email=something%40e6ar8r9c.mailosaur.net&invitation_token=K8Gedur6936wJ8WEyxi-&invited_to_program_team_id=1375"

Answer (score 1):

Because of how the commands are queued in cypress, `cy.visit(confirmationLink)` gets into the queue even before `then` block of `cy.mailosaurGetMessage` is executed and a value is assigned to `confirmationLink`. So, `confirmationLink` will be `Undefined` when it is actually used by your `cy.visit()` command.

This can be fixed by moving your `cy.visit()` into the `then` block. Your code will look as below.

```js
describe('Add new user to existing clinic team', () => {
  const serverId = 'e6ar8r9c';
  const testEmail = 'something@e6ar8r9c.mailosaur.net';

  it('signs in as admin', () => {
    cy.visit('******');
    cy.get('#user_email').type('*******');
    cy.get('#user_password').type('******');
    cy.get('.button').click();

    // show teams roster
    cy.get('.hide-for-large > a > .fas').click();
    cy.get('.vertical > :nth-child(1) > #programs-menu-btn > .fas').click();

    // click into the clinic team
    cy.get('table tbody > tr').contains('clinic team test apr 28#4').click();

    // click into the user roster for the clinic team
    cy.get('ul#program-team-tabs > li#team-icon-li').click();

    // enter user email to be added
    cy.get('#email').type(testEmail);
    cy.get('button.non-button').click();

    // get email
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
      sentTo: testEmail,
    }).then((email) => {
      expect(email.subject).to.equal('Existing user invitation instructions');
      cy.visit(email.html.links[0].href);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not accurate - cy.visit() gets executed ***after*** the `.then()` block of cy.mailosaurGetMessage() - but it get's ***queued*** before cy.mailosaurGetMessage() runs.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, wrap the visit in a `.then()`:

```js
// get email
cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
  sentTo: testEmail
}).then(email => {
  expect(email.subject).to.equal('Existing user invitation instructions');
  cy.log(email.subject)
  cy.log(email.html.links[0].href)
  confirmationLink = email.html.links[0].href
}).then(() => {
  // follow email link
  cy.visit(confirmationLink)    
})
```

Reason is, Cypress scans the test for commands, adds them to the command queue then runs the queue.

So the value of `confirmationLink` used when `cy.vist(confirmationLink)` is added to the queue is the value *at the beginning of the test*.

Using a `.then()` around any command defers adding to the queue until all preceding commands have run.

A better pattern is to pass the `confirmationLink` down the chain

```js
 // get email
cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
  sentTo: testEmail
}).then(email => {
  expect(email.subject).to.equal('Existing user invitation instructions');
  cy.log(email.subject)
  cy.log(email.html.links[0].href)
  confirmationLink = email.html.links[0].href

  return confirmationLink;  // pass to next command

}).then((confirmationLink ) => {
  // follow email link
  cy.visit(confirmationLink)    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress provides alias's to capture values from higher up the test.

For example,

```js
cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
  sentTo: testEmail
})
.then(email => {
  expect(email.subject).to.equal('Existing user invitation instructions');
  cy.log(email.subject)
  cy.log(email.html.links[0].href)
  return email.html.links[0].href
})
.as('confirmationLink')

cy.get('@confirmationLink')
  .then((confirmationLink ) => {
    cy.visit(confirmationLink)    
  })
```